# Failure of translation-invariance of an integral?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, measure-theory

Let $u$ be a smooth compactly supported function on $\mathbb{C}$. The $\overline{\partial}$-Poincaré lemma is the formula
$$\frac{{\partial}}{{\partial} \overline{z}}\frac{1}{\pi} \int_{\mathbb{C}} \frac{u(w)}{w - z} dx \wedge dy = u(z)$$
where $dx \wedge dy$ is the standard Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{C}$ ($w = x + iy$). In proving this, it is not immediately justified to pass the derivative through the integral, since for any fixed $w$ the integrand is an unbounded function of $z$, so, e.g., the Dominated Convergence Theorem fails. But one can make the change of variables $w \to w + z$ to remedy this, so the above equals
$$\frac{1}{\pi} \int_{\mathbb{C}} \frac{{\partial}}{{\partial} \overline{z}}\frac{u(w + z)}{w } dx \wedge dy.$$
From here one can make a standard limit argument using Stokes' theorem to finish the proof of the formula.

My confusion is that the integral $\frac{1}{\pi} \int_{\mathbb{C}} \frac{{\partial}}{{\partial}\overline{ z}}\frac{u(w + z)}{w } dx \wedge dy$ appears not be translation-invariant! Indeed, if we undo the substitution we made before, then the integrand $\frac{{\partial}}{{\partial} \overline{z}}\frac{u(w)}{w - z}$ is zero almost everywhere, since $\frac{u(w)}{w - z}$ is holomorphic as a function of $z$ away from its pole. Clearly something is wrong here, but why exactly is this substitution is unjustified? What exactly fails when the derivative is introduced to the integral?

Comment: What is wrong according to you ? Nothing fails.

Comment: For any given $z$, the expression $\int_{\Bbb{C}} \frac{\partial}{\partial \overline{z}} \frac{u(w)}{w - z} dx \wedge dy$ is the Lebesgue integral of a function in the variable $w$ that is $0$ almost everywhere, and therefore must equal zero. This is false if the formula is true. So something about the change of variables must be unjustified within the machinery of the Lebesgue integral.

Comment: I've written an answer in order to detail the reasoning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue turned out to be notational, rather than anything subtle with limits or integration. The function $\frac{\partial}{\partial \overline{z}} \frac{u(w)}{w - z}$ is not the function you get by composing $\frac{\partial}{\partial \overline{z}} \frac{u(w + z)}{w}$ with $w \mapsto w - z$; this notation confuses dummy variables with actual variables. The correct function we get from change of variables is more accurately notated as $$\frac{\partial}{\partial \overline{z}}\Big|_{(w, z) = (w_0 - z_0, z_0)} \frac{u(w + z)}{w},$$ as a function of $w_0, z_0$, treating $z, w$ as dummy variables.

Comment: +1. I like that notation for derivatives. (I'm talking about $\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial \overline z}\right|_{\text{conditions}}$). It combines the usefulness of $\frac{\partial}{\partial \overline z}$ with rigor. I think I learned it on the book in mechanics of Arnol'd.

Comment: Notation sometimes betrays us, and I always like a detective story when the scoundrel's evil act is discovered. +1

Answer (score 0):

After the translation, the next step makes use of Stokes' theorem in order to "kill" the derivative; then you will invoke Cauchy's formula to finish the computation. Now, it allows you to  reinterpret the expression $\frac{\partial}{\partial\bar{z}} \frac{1}{2\pi iz}$ as a representation of a Dirac delta with respect to the measure $\mathrm{d}x \wedge \mathrm{d}y$ in the complex plane. As a consequence, the measure has been replaced implicitly, otherwise indeed this treatment wouldn't have any meaning within the context of Lebesgue integration, since the integrand has an atomic support. In fact, this implicit manipulation itself is already "hidden" inside the proof of Cauchy's formula.